# Image not being displayed in correct order on swiping

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, swipe, touch-event

I am really new to android development and I have been trying to create an Image gallery app. Everything is working fine except when I am swiping to display next image its not displaying images in correct order but in random order. Also it is displaying images from a specific folder.

What should I do to solve this problem??

**ImageGallery.java**:

```
public class ImageGallery extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static ArrayList<Model_images> al_images = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean boolean_folder;
    Adapter_PhotosFolder obj_adapter;
    GridView gv_folder;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);
        gv_folder = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gv_folder);

        gv_folder.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PhotosActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("value",i);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ImageGallery.this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) && (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale( ImageGallery.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( ImageGallery.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        }else {
            Log.e("Else","Else");
            fn_imagespath();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Model_images> fn_imagespath() {
        al_images.clear();

        int int_position = 0;
        Uri uri;
        Cursor cursor;
        int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;

        String absolutePathOfImage;
        uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};

        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy + " DESC");

        column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        column_index_folder_name = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
            Log.e("Column", absolutePathOfImage);
            Log.e("Folder", cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name));

            for (int i = 0; i < al_images.size(); i++) {
                if (al_images.get(i).getStr_folder().equals(cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name))) {
                    boolean_folder = true;
                    int_position = i;
                    break;
                } else {
                    boolean_folder = false;
                }
            }


            if (boolean_folder) {

                ArrayList<String> al_path = new ArrayList<>();
                al_path.addAll(al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath());
                al_path.add(absolutePathOfImage);
                al_images.get(int_position).setAl_imagepath(al_path);

            } else {
                ArrayList<String> al_path = new ArrayList<>();
                al_path.add(absolutePathOfImage);
                Model_images obj_model = new Model_images();
                obj_model.setStr_folder(cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name));
                obj_model.setAl_imagepath(al_path);

                al_images.add(obj_model);


            }


        }


        for (int i = 0; i < al_images.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("FOLDER", al_images.get(i).getStr_folder());
            for (int j = 0; j < al_images.get(i).getAl_imagepath().size(); j++) {
                Log.e("FILE", al_images.get(i).getAl_imagepath().get(j));
            }
        }
        obj_adapter = new Adapter_PhotosFolder(getApplicationContext(),al_images);
        gv_folder.setAdapter(obj_adapter);
        return al_images;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_PERMISSIONS: {
                for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        fn_imagespath();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText( ImageGallery.this, "The app was not allowed to read or write to your storage. Hence, it cannot function properly. Please consider granting it this permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**PhotosActivity.java:**

```
public class PhotosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int int_position;
    private GridView gridView;
    GridViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);
        gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gv_folder);
        int_position = getIntent().getIntExtra("value", 0);
        adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, al_images,int_position);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String abc = "file://" + al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                i.putExtra("abc",abc);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**FullImageActivity.java:**

```
public class FullImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageSwitcher Switch;
    ImageView images;
    float initialX;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private  int int_position;
    ArrayList<String> al_path = new ArrayList<>();
    int position1,position;
    String absolutePathOfImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_image);
        Switch = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        images = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullImage);

        // Selected image id
        position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String value = extras.getString("abc");

        Glide.with(FullImageActivity.this)
                .load(value)
                .skipMemoryCache(false)
                .into(images);

        int_position = getIntent().getIntExtra("value", 0);
        al_path.addAll(al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath());
        al_path.add(absolutePathOfImage);
        al_images.get(int_position).setAl_imagepath(al_path);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                initialX = event.getX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                float finalX = event.getX();
                if (initialX > finalX)
                {
                    Glide.with(FullImageActivity.this)
                            .load(al_path.get(int_position+1))
                            .skipMemoryCache(false)
                            .into(images);
                    Switch.showNext();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Next Image",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    int_position ++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(int_position> 0)
                    {
                        cursor.moveToPosition(int_position);
                        Glide.with(FullImageActivity.this)
                                .load(al_path.get(int_position))
                                .skipMemoryCache(false)
                                .into(images);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "previous Image",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Switch.showPrevious();
                        int_position= int_position-1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No More Images To Swipe",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**GridViewAdapter.java:**

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model_images> {

    Context context;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu = new ArrayList<>();
    int int_position;


    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu,int int_position) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_adapter__photos_folder, al_menu);
        this.al_menu = al_menu;
        this.context = context;
        this.int_position = int_position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        Log.e("ADAPTER LIST SIZE", al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size() + "");
        return al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        if (al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size() > 0) {
            return al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size();
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_adapter__photos_folder, parent, false);
            viewHolder.tv_foldern = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_folder);
            viewHolder.tv_foldersize = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_folder2);
            viewHolder.iv_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.tv_foldern.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.tv_foldersize.setVisibility(View.GONE);



        Glide.with(context).load("file://" + al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(viewHolder.iv_image);


        return convertView;

    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_foldern, tv_foldersize;
        ImageView iv_image;

    }
}
```